# jQuery - Call function from .each() function

Tags: jquery

I have a first function :

```
$(document).find('.entries > div').each(color_red);
function color_red() {
    $(this).css('color','red')
    console.log('red')
}
```

Which works fine.

Then I have another, separate function :

```
$( '.entries > div' ).each(function(){
            
        var thetab = $(this).attr('tab');
            
        if(thetab == 'all') {
            $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass( 'show' );
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('show').addClass( 'hide' )
        }           
})
```

It also works fine.

Now, in the first if statement, I would like to call the first function :

```
if(thetab == 'all' || thetab == tab) {
            $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass( 'show' );
            color_red();
        }
```

Somehow this doesn't work. The function is executed (the console displays "red" for each div), but the color isn't applied. I understood that the "THIS" is not passed correctly to the second function (sorry if I'm not expressing myself correctly) but I don't know the correct syntax

Comment: You can do something like : `color_red.bind(this)()` to execute your second function with the context of the first one. But passing your element as a parameter of the function would be better. `.each` function already does this, with the index as first parameter and the element as second parameter.